# Get the coordinates of a letter in a SVG text element

Tags: javascript, svg

Say I have a very basic SVG:

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 50">
  <path transform="translate(X,Y)" fill="none" stroke="red" d="M11,11.1c-3.9,1.2-12.4,9-10.4,12.2s14.9-0.8,15.5-2.1s-4-2.7-4-2.7"></path>
  <text transform="translate(10,25)">Hello World.</text>
</svg>
```

I know the height and width of the `<path>` (from some other algorithm) and the position of the `<text>` (from the `transform` attribute shown above).

**How can I know the X and Y coordinates of the letter `W`?**

My goal here is to set the translation of the path so that it appears just below the letter `W`.

---

To give you a better idea of the end goal, here's what I'm trying to do: I want to automatically replace all `<text>` in a svg by paths that I've drawn to match the font (Permanent Marker). This way I can create a realistic handwriting effect (see here for a **[live demo](http://whiteboard-comics.com/good_time_for_drinking=f(week_day))**: [whiteboard-comics.com/good_time_for_drinking=f(week_day)](http://whiteboard-comics.com/good_time_for_drinking=f(week_day)))

So far, I start with a `<text>` and my images look like this:
[image: example with font]

Then I replace by hand, letter by letter, in Illustrator, the entire text. And it end up looking like this:
[image: example with hand replaced letters]

And when I do it algorithmically (just based on the coordinates of the `<text>` element and the width of each hand drawn character as a `<path>`), it becomes this:
[image: example with auto replaced letters]

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/text.html#__svg__SVGTextContentElement__getStartPositionOfChar

Comment: Wow really ?! Thanks